# Select em Python (com BD: Postgres)

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

Não estou conseguindo fazer um select no banco PostgreSQL. Python 3.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", dbname='postgres', user='postgres', password=postgres)

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("select id_log, nm_ip, dh_chamada, nm_tipo, nm_contexto, cd_http, in_tamanho from tb_log")

cur.fetchone()
```

Resultado erro:

> ```
> cur.execute("select id_log, nm_ip, dh_chamada, nm_tipo, nm_contexto, cd_http, in_tamanho from tb_log")
> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "tb_log" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...amada, nm_tipo, nm_contexto, cd_http, in_tamanho from tb_log
>                                                                  ^
> ```

Base PostGres:

```
SELECT id_log, nm_ip, dh_chamada, nm_tipo, nm_contexto, cd_http, in_tamanho
        FROM tb_log;
```

Resultado:

1,'12             ','2018-06-07 13:03:13','HEAD ','/FDSFDS',200
,1000

Comment: Tem certeza que selecionou o mesmo banco em ambos os exemplos?

Comment: Sim. O mesmo BD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique em qual *schema* a tabela `tb_log` está contida! Por exemplo, se a sua tabela estiver contida em um `schema` chamado `xpto`, sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
    id_log,
    nm_ip,
    dh_chamada,
    nm_tipo,
    nm_contexto,
    cd_http,
    in_tamanho
FROM
    xpto.tb_log;
```

Certamente a aplicação ou a `ROLE` que a aplicação está usando para executar a consulta, não está com a variável de ambiente [`SEARCH_PATH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-set.html) setada corretamente.

Para setar a variável de ambiente manualmente durante a sessão, e tornar o *schema* `xpto` acessível:

```
SET SEARCH_PATH = xpto, public;
```

Para setar a variável de ambiente permanentemente para uma determinada `ROLE`:

```
ALTER ROLE app_role SET search_path = xpto, public;
```

Comment: Continua com erro:
Continua com erro - Criei a tabela em um novo schema, setei a variável ambiente e nada

  c.execute("SELECT id_log, nm_ip, dh_chamada, nm_tipo, nm_contexto, cd_http, in_tamanho FROM sipje.tb_log;")
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "sipje.tb_log" does not exist
LINE 1: ...a, nm_tipo, nm_contexto, cd_http, in_tamanho FROM sipje.tb_l...

Comment: @AlexSandro: O nome do *schema* na qual a `tb_log` está contida se chama mesmo `sipje` ?! Você não está confundindo o nome da *database* com o nome do *schema* ?

Comment: Olá @Lacobus o banco se chama SIPJE e o schema por enquanto tem o mesmo nome - Mas já consegui resolver - conforme publicado acima. Muitíssimo obrigado pela atenção. Vou guardar essas informações sobre a ROLE e as variáveis de ambiente.

Answer (score 0):

Caro Anderson - alterei a linha

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", dbname='postgres', user='postgres', password=postgres)

para:

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", database='SIPJE', user='postgres', password=postgres)

E funcionou ...
Muito obrigado.

Comment: Então não era o mesmo banco :D

Comment: Muito obrigado.